# web.xml welcome file on jboss

Tags: java, web, jboss7.x, web.xml

I have ear app with ejb and web modules. In web module in web-inf I have web.xml like this:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>view.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And it does not work. JBoss don't show this page on startup. How to solve this?

Comment: view.xhtml located in webapp not in web-inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the tag without the q namespace? like:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>view.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Does your view.xhtml file physically exist? The spec says that the file should exist, even if it will not be used (if it's generated by a servlet).

Comment: maybe there is another way to open page view.xhtml? not with welcome-file?

Comment: Are you able to access the file directly from your browser?